# How do I change the Terraform Provider.aws version

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a pipeline in Jenkins that allows me to change my AWS infrastructure with Terraform. The build failed yesterday because and I noticed the provider.aws changed from:

```
provider.aws: version = "~> 3.15"
```

to

```
provider.aws: version = "~> 3.20".
```

I understand that this includes breaking changes.

Does anyone know how I can manually change that number manually back to 3.15?

Comment: The answer is different for Terraform 0.13 than for 0.12 (or older). Which is yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Terraform 0.11](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/providers.html#provider-versions) it was done with `version` attribute when the provider was declared, e.g.:

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "3.15"
}
```

These days e.g. [Terraform 0.13](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/provider-requirements.html) it is done in the `required_providers` section, e.g.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.15"
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure, but I think in Terraform 0.12 both could be used.

Comment: Hi tks for your response. However we do not have that value set in our terraform code. I checked for it yesterday. For instance, for out Testing env it just has ```provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}
```No mention of the version. I cant find where it is set or understand why its updating by itself.

Comment: Then you can add it.

Comment: ok I will add and try run the build again. tks